# issue with loading a model in Keras in Colab

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, transformer-model

I've saved my model as follows:
model.save('/content/model')

When my model is saved: I got this WARNING:

```
WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as embeddings_layer_call_fn, embeddings_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, encoder_layer_call_fn, encoder_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, pooler_layer_call_fn while saving (showing 5 of 430). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Reduce to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 then broadcast to ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',).
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: /content/model/assets
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: /content/model/assets
WARNING:absl:<keras.layers.recurrent.LSTMCell object at 0x7f95000fac10> has the same name 'LSTMCell' as a built-in Keras object. Consider renaming <class 'keras.layers.recurrent.LSTMCell'> to avoid naming conflicts when loading with `tf.keras.models.load_model`. If renaming is not possible, pass the object in the `custom_objects` parameter of the load function.
WARNING:absl:<keras.layers.recurrent.LSTMCell object at 0x7f950018eb50> has the same name 'LSTMCell' as a built-in Keras object. Consider renaming <class 'keras.layers.recurrent.LSTMCell'> to avoid naming conflicts when loading with `tf.keras.models.load_model`. If renaming is not possible, pass the object in the `custom_objects` parameter of the load function.
```

Now,when I try to load the model I got error message:
model_CSP = keras.models.load_model('/content/model')

I got an error message as follows:

```
2022-06-22 01:57:09.702116: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:39] Overriding allow_growth setting because the TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH environment variable is set. Original config value was 0.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Do_predection_Combined_model_.py", line 730, in <module>
    model_CSP = keras.models.load_model('/content/CSP_model')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 573, in assert_same_structure
    % (str(e), str1, str2))
ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.

First structure: type=tuple str=(({'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)},), {'training': False})

Second structure: type=tuple str=((TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs'),), {'token_type_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128), dtype=tf.int32, name='token_type_ids'), 'training': False, 'attention_mask': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128), dtype=tf.int32, name='attention_mask')})

More specifically: Substructure "type=dict str={'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)}" is a sequence, while substructure "type=TensorSpec str=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128), dtype=tf.int32, name='inputs')" is not
Entire first structure:
(({'input_ids': .},), {'training': .})
Entire second structure:
((.,), {'token_type_ids': ., 'training': ., 'attention_mask': .})

'''
```

I don't know what is wrong? I follow the best practice in saving and loading a model. but I still get this error.

Edit the question:

I think I make a big mistake when I choose Keras API to train my model. After I spend a lot of time designing and training my model. I can't save and reload again. I don't know why the ML experiments recommend this API for beginners. I tried all practice for saving and loading my model and  All of them failed. get tired of this

Comment: Check this issue. It has a few suggestions as solutions - https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/14345

Comment: @VishalBalaji Thanks. I used tf.saved_model.load('/content/model') is worked. but it can not use model_CSP.summary() or model_CSP..predict()

Comment: it seems the loaded model is not karas object.